# How to store multiple json objects in angular7

Tags: angular7

How to store multiple json objects in to an array in angular7?

I am trying to save array of json objects like below :

```
employees: any;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getemployee().subscribe 
    data => this.employees == data,
    );
}
```

below is the response i am getting from the backend :

```
(32) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "59744", employee_name: "Sample API ", employee_salary: "18000", employee_age: "20", profile_image: ""}
1: {id: "59747", employee_name: "Test", employee_salary: "123", employee_age: "456", profile_image: ""}
2: {id: "59748", employee_name: "hello#amdon", employee_salary: "10000", employee_age: "35", profile_image: ""}
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

create an array of objects of the following structure.

```
  //response  data structure
   export class ResponseData {
     id:string
     employee_name: string;
     employee_salary: string; 
     employee_age: string;
     profile_image:string;
   }
```

**component.ts**

```
export class Test implements OnInit { 

 responseData:ResponseData[]=[]; 

 constructor(){ }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.getemployee().subscribe((data)=>{
       if(data != null) {
       console.log('response received');
       this.responseData = data;
       }
    });   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
 Component.ts:

     employees: IEmployeeData[] = []; 

     constructor(){ }

     ngOnInit() {
        this.getemployee().subscribe((data: IEmployeeData) => {
           if(data) this.employees = data;
        });   
     }

   interface IEmployeeData { 
     id:string
     employee_name: string;
     employee_salary: string; 
     employee_age: string;
     profile_image:string;
   };
```